# Generating links for Google Analytics and Omniture

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools, adobe-analytics

I am trying to build URLs for Google Analytics and Omniture.

GA is simple enough, and those URLs can be built using http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55578

```
Campaign Source: *   (referrer: google, citysearch, newsletter4)
Campaign Medium: *   (marketing medium: cpc, banner, email)
Campaign Term:   (identify the paid keywords)
Campaign Content:    (use to differentiate ads)
Campaign Name*:
```

Does anyone know how Omniture links are constructed? Do they support this kind of URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omniture does not grab predefined var=value params from a URL like GA.

What you can do though is use omniture's s.getQueryParam() plugin to grab the same parameters generated by that GA tool, and put them in s.prop and/or s.eVar variables.

Comment: Thanks. Also you have a *fantastic* name.

Comment: Just so you guys know, there's a debugger for Omniture at http://omniture.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/534 and a debugger for GA at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna  Both these have helped me kind of a lot...

Answer (score 1):

The basic Omniture campaign tracking is based on the s.campaign parameter, which can be then re-defined (classified) using the SAINT tool. The "cid" (default) URL parameter only takes one value, by default a running number, which is then classified with SAINT. Fetching the value can be done with a plug-in, such as getQueryParam(), which is recommended.

I don't recommend using prop or eVar variables too much on this, since without DataWarehouse or Discover you can't really use several of them in a segment (max. 2) and this makes using 5 parameters quite useless.

The SAINT tool together with the campaign parameter is quite powerful and should be enough for basic needs.